# Multi level dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a sub-level to my dropdown navigation which I just can't seem to get.

I can't figure out how to process the JS code to handle the sub-level, or the css (it doesn't work as expected, and the menu items are going down in rows)

The fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/WPNMN/7/

Edit: posted early, I've tried adding the functions for `ul li ul` as well as just `ul` and `ul li ul li` as well as `ul li` but still to no avail.

Does anyone have any pointers on where to start?

Edit: I've fixed the jsfiddle I've linked too, it wasn't even displaying how it should of been to start with not sure what's going on but sorted it now.

Comment: The jsfiddle URL doesn't include the fiddle id (it just points to the main page)

Comment: Where is your jsfiddle?

Comment: plese use jsbin. jsfiddle is very slow :P

Comment: A fiddle is nice (if the link would be correct) but I still would like to see the code here too.

Comment: Sorry - been up for far too long without sleep! The fiddle is there

Comment: Wow God has been downvoted :)

Comment: @undefined - not happy :(

Comment: @undefined Yeah, he finally got what he deserved! xD

Answer (score 2):

I have update you js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.rs_nav_menu li').hover(
function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children('ul').fadeIn('fast');
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children('ul').fadeOut();
}
);
});
```

and some css check the [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WPNMN/6/)

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your menu should look like, but when it comes to dropdown menus I like the [Son of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) solution. It's a css only solution (except for browsers that do not support the :hover pseudo-class) with valid html.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick; no need to use any jQuery or javascript for it...

```
ul ul { display:none; }
ul a:hover ul { display:block }
```

Just make sure you set the ul within the a tag